# Setting up Expire Headers with PHP

Tags: php, header

could anyone help me with setting up Expire Headers using PHP only,
.htaccess is no good, because my host won't enable mod_expires on apache.

So basically I'm looking for a way to do:

```
Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 365 days"
</FilesMatch>
```

with php only.

its also important to have different expire periods for different filetypes, so I tried using something like:

```
header ("content-type: image/jpg; charset: UTF-8");
header ("cache-control: must-revalidate");
$offset = 48 * 60 * 60;
$expire = "expires: " . gmdate ("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
header ($expire);
```

for each type of files, but nothing happened.

---

the headers after adding the PHP code, and taken from private session:

```
Response Headersview source
Date    Mon, 25 Apr 2011 19:47:10 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.1
P3P CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Expires Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Last-Modified   Mon, 25 Apr 2011 19:47:10 GMT
Content-Encoding    gzip
Pragma  no-cache
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110323 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.16 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729) FirePHP/0.5
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.7,he;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://localhost/-----------------
Cookie  fboard_settings[current_view]=flat; style_cookie=null; phpbb3_4s1go_k=; phpbb3_4s1go_u=2; phpbb3_4s1go_sid=8a3835a63834e9851b0cde3e2f6cff63; jw_clean_pro_tpl=jw_clean_pro; acpSearchCookie[searchphrase]=any; acpSearchCookie[acpSearch]=%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A9+...; acpSearchCookie[cid]=0; acpSearchCookie[field_city]=0; 14a2bb08766d6180968b7925b7902d70=bgd3h1uj5dctoevtdiaj1jtmg6; 3e2fd857422e2463a01f9631f718017a=nbdjbmjsn9ee8ng90ui816hec2
x-insight   activate
```

Comment: "Nothing happened"? You mean, it didn't output the header?

Comment: Yeah, please add more detail. Where are you inserting this PHP code exactly?

Comment: well, checking the Yslow or PageSpeed i see the browser chaching notes, i'm inserting the code in my index.php on top, and i don't get any errors as headers sent. so checking the Net tab i see: Expires Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified Mon, 25 Apr 2011 09:05:17 GMT
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma no-cache

Answer (score 10):

According to your comment in the question it looks like your system is running with a PHP setting of `session.cache_limiter = nocache`. This would automatically send the following headers:

```
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

Only the `Expires` header you mention differs a bit (afaik Joomla uses that very datetime, if i'm not mistaken). But all in all it makes no difference, because both dates are in the past.

You should try with `session_cache_limiter(false);` in your code, to stop PHP sending its default caching headers:

```
function sendHeader($sType, $iLastModified, $iSecondsToCache)
{

    $aType = array(
        'ico'   => 'image/x-icon',
        'jpg'   => 'image/jpeg',
        'png'   => 'image/png',
        'gif'   => 'image/gif',
        'js'    => 'text/javascript',
        'css'   => 'text/css',
        'swf'   => 'application/x-shockwave-flash'
    );
    if (!isset($aType[$sType]))
        die('No mime type found for ' . $sType);

    //$sLastModified = gmdate('r', $iLastModified);
    $sLastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $iLastModified) . ' GMT';

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
    {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $sLastModified)
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
            exit;
        }
    }

    session_cache_limiter(false);
    //header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', $iLastModified + $iSecondsToCache));
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $iLastModified + $iSecondsToCache) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . $sLastModified);
    header('Content-Type: ' . $aType[$sType]);

}

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$iLastModified = strtotime('2011-04-25 07:08:09');
$iSecondsToCache = 48 * 60 * 60;
sendHeader('jpg', $iLastModified, $iSecondsToCache);

// stream sample image/jpeg content
$rGD = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 20);
$iColor = imagecolorallocate($rGD, 255, 255, 255);
imagestring($rGD, 1, 5, 5,  'Image to be cached', $iColor);
imagejpeg($rGD);
imagedestroy($rGD);
exit;
```

**EDIT**:

Meanwhile it's more probable to me, that Joomla is causing the problem. If the test code has access to Joomla libraries, try inserting:

```
jimport('joomla.environment.response');
JResponse::allowCache(true);
```

at the very top of the function and replace each `header` instruction with `JResponse::setHeader`.

Comment: well this is not working. i supposed to see a content-type header with expire for jpg images, right? well it's not at the request / response

Comment: Yep, you should've seen the headers of the script. Can you please clear caches and cookies, execute the code again and show me the very first raw HTTP response after execution? You got Fiddler or s/t to monitor HTTP communication, right? And it maybe helpful to know if you are running under some PHP framework like Zend Framework, or bare PHP.

Comment: the site i'm working on is based on joomla, on localhost setting my apache to run mod_expires and with htaccess i get the expires, the problem is on the host. i use tamperdata or the net panel on firebug to see my requests

Comment: Are you testing the code of the answers on your localhost? Nevermind, you added the headers.

Comment: You had `mod_expires` disabled before testing, do you?

Comment: testing where? local or live? both had same headers... the headers in the post are from my local, and on my apache mod_expires running, but on host i get same headers with mod_expires off

Comment: Hm, I'm not really into Joomla, but afaik there are some Joomla extensions that modify Expires headers, too. Maybe one of the Joomla extensions is causing the problem? Try disabling them one by one. Or Joomla causes it itself? Check the core libraries of Joomla for Expires headers. Another thing you could check is, whether PHP `auto_prepend` is somehow used to send Expires headers.

Comment: well i'm not using any additional plugins or anything, almost core joomla with custom components, joomla itself provides only cache control or gzip compression to the site, but not setting expire headers. anyway, i'll look into it, maybe joomla itself is the issue. but if joomla sending headers before i do, howcome i don't get the Headers Sent error?

Comment: If the test code is executed under Joomla control, Joomla could use own header() instructions to override existing ones (of the test code in our case). Then you wouldn't see any "Headers already sent". Try switching off the Joomla backend cache and see if it works.

Comment: EDIT: sorry, I meant switch the Joomla backend cache **on**, to see if that would change the headers being sent.

Comment: well actually joomla cache is file controlled, so by deleting the cached files it removes system cache completely. i think that there might be no easy way of doing this with joomla but using htaccess. i'll keep looking anyway... thanx anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer with a last try though ^^. Other than that I'm out, my Joomla experience is to weak to go further.

Comment: In my case session_cache_limiter doesn't change headers, it still contains no-store, no-cache. Looks like some PHP settings which forbids an override throught the script.

Answer (score 1):

That helps me for ajax queries:

```
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s',time()+60*60*8 ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
```

Comment: Do you have output before setting headers? do: error_repoerting(E_ALL); and look for something about headers

Comment: actually i don't have access to my php.ini, so i'm using the host settings for errors, but i guess headers sent error should pop if the header is incorrect

Comment: if error_reporting setted to e_NONE you'll not see the warnings

Comment: try to create an empty php file with the only those lines and look at headers

Comment: actually i'm using TamperData to see my header, and i see that there is Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache...
also, tried changing Content-Type to image/jpg but in response i'm still seing text/html

Comment: @Yuriy Vikulov: I'm sorry, but I am afraid the code you provide would not cache anything at all. It would **disable** caching, which is very good for most Ajax request (as you mentioned), but the opposite of what the OP is asking for.